# ggplot on R Shiny, vs RStudio

Tags: r, shiny, shiny-server

For some reason a ggplot in "R Shiny" is different than that of plain R in RStudio

the runnable Shiny code is

```
library(ggplot2)
library(scales)
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(

  # Sidebar layout with a input and output definitions
  sidebarLayout(

    # Inputs
    sidebarPanel(

      # Select variable for y-axis
      selectInput(inputId = "y", 
                  label = "Y-axis:",
                  choices = c("Water Level" = "WaterLevel", 
                              "Discharge Debit" = "DischargeDebit"), 
                  selected = "WaterLevel"),

      selectInput(inputId = "z", 
                  label = "station:",
                  choices = c(
                    "NORTH SASKATCHEWAN RIVER NEAR DEER CREEK"="05EF001",
                    "BATTLE RIVER NEAR PONOKA"="05FA001",
                    "BATTLE RIVER AT DUHAMEL"="05FA011",
                    "PIGEON LAKE AT PIGEON LAKE PROVINCIAL PARK"="05FA013",
                    "MASKWA CREEK NO. 1 ABOVE BEARHILLS LAKE"="05FA014"
), 
selected = "05EF001")

    ),

    # Output
    mainPanel(
      plotOutput(outputId = "lineplot")
    )
  )
)



server <- function(input, output) {
file = "http://dd.weather.gc.ca/hydrometric/csv/SK/hourly/SK_hourly_hydrometric.csv"
skdat <- read.csv(file, head=T, sep=",", dec=".", stringsAsFactors = F)
colnames(skdat) <- c("ID", "Date", "WaterLevel", "Grade1", "Symbol1",
                     "QAQC-1", "DischargeDebit", "Grade2", "Symbol2",
                     "QAQC-2")

subds <- subset(skdat, ID=input$z)
subds$datetime <- as.POSIXct(subds$Date, format = "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%OS")
output$lineplot <- renderPlot({ 
  ggplot(subds, aes(x = datetime, y = !!as.name(input$y))) + geom_line() 
})  


}

# Create a Shiny app object
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

and the RStudio code that produces the correct graph is

```
library(ggplot2)
library(scales)
library(shiny)
library(stringi)



file = "http://dd.weather.gc.ca/hydrometric/csv/SK/hourly/SK_hourly_hydrometric.csv"
skdat <- read.csv(file, head=T, sep=",", dec=".", stringsAsFactors = F)
colnames(skdat) <- c("ID", "Date", "WaterLevel", "Grade1", "Symbol1",
                     "QAQC-1", "DischargeDebit", "Grade2", "Symbol2",
                     "QAQC-2")

subds <- subset(skdat, ID=='05EF001')
#subds$datetime <- as.POSIXct(subds$Date, format = "%Y-%m-%dT%H%m%S")
subds$datetime <- as.POSIXct(subds$Date, format = "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%OS")#subds$datetime <- as.POSIXct(subds$Date, format = "%Y-%m-%dT%H%m%S-06:00")

p2 <- ggplot(subds, aes(x = datetime, y = WaterLevel)) + geom_line()
p2
```

there must be something wrong with the rendering linein the shiny code?

```
output$lineplot <- renderPlot({ 
  ggplot(subds, aes(x = datetime, y = !!as.name(input$y))) + geom_line() 
})
```

The `Shiny` graph comes out a a black block with no line that can be seen.
any help with this would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks Jake!! that helped this below did the trick

```
#subds <- subset(skdat, ID=input$z)
#subds$datetime <- as.POSIXct(subds$Date, format = "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%OS")
#output$lineplot <- renderPlot({ 
#  ggplot(subds, aes(x = datetime, y = !!as.name(input$y))) + geom_line() 
#})  


output$lineplot <- renderPlot({
  subds <- subset(skdat, ID == input$z)
  subds$datetime <- as.POSIXct(subds$Date, format = "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%OS")
  ggplot(subds, aes(x = datetime, y = !!as.name(input$y))) +
    geom_line()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There isn't a difference in `ggplot2` graphics between viewing in RStudio or Shiny.  There **is** a difference in the code that you used to make both.

1. No logical statement in your subset (you used `=` when you intended `==`)
2. With 1, your data set needs to be wrapped in a `reactive`
3. While you can use `as.name`, if you're going full `tidyeval` you might as well use the proper match of `sym`.

The code below works, but you might want to check the IDs you want to filter on in the input conditions.  Unsure if those are to be added later, but they don't exist in your data as is.

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(scales)
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(

  # Sidebar layout with a input and output definitions
  sidebarLayout(

    # Inputs
    sidebarPanel(

      # Select variable for y-axis
      selectInput(inputId = "y", 
                  label = "Y-axis:",
                  choices = c("Water Level" = "WaterLevel", 
                              "Discharge Debit" = "DischargeDebit"), 
                  selected = "WaterLevel"),

      selectInput(inputId = "z", 
                  label = "station:",
                  choices = c(
                    "NORTH SASKATCHEWAN RIVER NEAR DEER CREEK"="05EF001",
                    "BATTLE RIVER NEAR PONOKA"="05FA001",
                    "BATTLE RIVER AT DUHAMEL"="05FA011",
                    "PIGEON LAKE AT PIGEON LAKE PROVINCIAL PARK"="05FA013",
                    "MASKWA CREEK NO. 1 ABOVE BEARHILLS LAKE"="05FA014"
                  ), 
                  selected = "05EF001")

    ),

    # Output
    mainPanel(
      plotOutput(outputId = "lineplot")
    )
  )
)



server <- function(input, output) {
  file = "http://dd.weather.gc.ca/hydrometric/csv/SK/hourly/SK_hourly_hydrometric.csv"
  skdat <- read.csv(file, head=T, sep=",", dec=".", stringsAsFactors = F)
  colnames(skdat) <- c("ID", "Date", "WaterLevel", "Grade1", "Symbol1",
                       "QAQC-1", "DischargeDebit", "Grade2", "Symbol2",
                       "QAQC-2")

  # Switched the date time to skdat from subds to not mess with reactivity until later
  skdat$datetime <- as.POSIXct(skdat$Date, format = "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%OS")

  # You need to have a logical condition for subset, == not =
  subds <- reactive({subset(skdat, ID == input$z)})

  # Switched the use of as.name to rlang::sym 
  output$lineplot <- renderPlot({ 
    ggplot(subds(), aes(x = datetime, y = !!sym(input$y))) + geom_line() 
  })  


}

# Create a Shiny app object
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: Can you help here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65021945/shiny-and-ggplot2-for-getting-location-of-letters-in-r